# ko.validation.group not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have web-application in knockout.js javascript framework.

I have following model:

```
function ClientContactRepository() {
    // View Model State
    this.model = null;

    // Return View Model
    this.GetModel = function () {

        this.model = {

            ID: ko.observable(),
            Title: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
            FirstName: ko.validatedObservable().extend({ required: true }),
            MI: ko.observable(),
            LastName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
            SecurityTab: ko.validation.group([this.FirstName,this.LastName], { deep: true })


            submit: function () {
                alert(this.SecurityTab.length);

            }
        };

        return this.model;
    };


}
```

i am trying to group on FirstName and LastName inside SecurityTab, but on Save click event every time i am getting `this.SecurityTab.length =0`.

what can be reason ? why group is not working ?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the html to look at the bindings?

Comment: try  `alert(this.SecurityTab().length);`

Comment: tried this.SecurityTab().length, but it also doesn't work

Comment: why would firstname be a validated observable and lastname not?

Comment: do we need to add any settings in validate.configure() or validate.init()  ?